# Google App Engine Local (Development) IPython Shell

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ipython

In my local Google app engine development environment, I would like to use an ipython shell, especially to be able to check out models with data that was created via `dev_server.py`, 
very much like how django's `manage.py shell` command works.

(This means that the ipython shell should be started after `sys.path` was fixed and `app.yaml` was read and analyzed, and the local datastore is ready)

Any simple solution for this?

Comment: This seems like a good start: http://pythonwise.blogspot.co.il/2011/02/appengine-work-environment.html

Answer (score 7):

For starters, you can put your application root directory and the SDK root directory (`google_appengine`) in your Python path.  You'll also need a few libraries like `yaml`, either installed or added to the library path from the SDK's `lib` directory.  Then you can import modules and call some features.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine')
```

Of course, as soon as a code path tries to make a service call, the library will raise an exception, saying it isn't bound to anything.  To bind the service libraries to test stubs, use the testbed library:

```
>>> from google.appengine.ext import testbed
>>> tb = testbed.Testbed()
>>> tb.activate()
>>> tb.init_datastore_v3_stub()
>>> from google.appengine.ext import db
>>> import models
>>> m = models.Entry()
>>> m.title = ‘Test’
>>> m.put()
```

To tell the datastore test stub to use your development server's datastore file, pass the path to the file to `init_datastore_v3_stub()` as the `datastore_file` argument.  See the doc comment for the method in `google.appengine.ext.testbed` for more information.

For more information on testbed: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting

Comment: This is what I use for testing in a clean environment.  I am looking for something simple as executing `gae_shell` to start a local shell with the "current" local datastore.

Comment: What I described seems easily scriptable with IPython, including passing the datastore file to the stub initializer.  Do you need it to do more?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you'll need to use this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api

For IPython support you have two options:

(1) If you're working with Python 2.7 (and IPython 0.13) you will need to use this to embed an IPython shell:

```
from IPython.frontend.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
shell = TerminalInteractiveShell(user_ns=namespace)
shell.mainloop()
```

(2) If you're working with Python 2.5 (and IPython 0.10.2) you will need to use this line to embed an IPython shell:

```
from IPython.Shell import IPShellEmbed
ipshell = IPShellEmbed(user_ns=namespace, banner=banner)
ipshell()
```

This is the one that I use: https://gist.github.com/4624108 so you just type..

```
>> python console.py your-app-id
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you run **dev_appserver.py** 
you will get

```
starting module "default" running at: http://127.0.0.1:8080
Starting admin server at : http://localhost:8000
```

so basically what you want to do is to access  http://localhost:8000 and there you will find "Interactive Console" you can use it to play around with